# Notification with Laravel, with the name of the user

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I have a little problem. When the user creates their company on the platform, they receive a notification via email.   The notification is going, and I want to put the user name inside the body of the message, how do I?

**controller Company**

```
public function store(CompanyRequest $request)
{
    $dataForm = $request->all();
    $dataForm['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

    // Upload de imagem do S3
    if ($request->hasFile('photo_url')) {
        $file = $request->file('photo_url');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $filepath = 'company/photo_url/' . $name;
        Storage::disk('s3')->put($filepath, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
        $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filepath);

        $dataForm['photo_url'] = $url;
    }

    $company = $this->company->create($dataForm);

    // Conveniando o empresa criada para o usuário que está logado
    $user = User::with('company')->find(auth()->user()->id);
    $user->update(['company_id' => $company->id,]);

    // Notifica o usuário quando ele cria a Empresa
    try{
        $user->notify(new CreateNewCompany());
    }
    catch (\Error $error) {
        $company->delete();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Não foi possivel notificar o Usuário']);
    }


    // Testa a empresa foi criada ou não.
    if (!$company) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Não foi possível cadastrar a Empresa']);
    }
    return response()->json(['user' => $user], 201);
}
```

**Notification -> CreateNewCompany**

```
 public function toMail($notifiable)
{

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Sua empresa foi criada!')
        ->greeting('Olá, { $user }')
        ->line('Obrigado por se cadastrar. Sua conta já está ativa!')
        ->line('Obrigado por usar nossa plataforma!');
}
```

> Olá, { $user }
>           Obrigado por se cadastrar. Sua conta já está ativa!
>
> ```
>     Obrigado por usar nossa plataforma!
>
>     Regards,<br>Laravel
> ```

Comment: create a variable, say `$temp`, which will have the entire greeting including `$user` variable, and pass `$temp`, like this `->greeting($temp)`

Comment: Add a property to the Notification class and pass it as an argument to the constructor from your controller

Comment: Ok, test here guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case your user is the `$notifiable` object which is passed to the `toMail` method, so you can access the user like so:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{

return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject('Sua empresa foi criada!')
    ->greeting('Olá, '.$notifiable->name )
    ->line('Obrigado por se cadastrar. Sua conta já está ativa!')
    ->line('Obrigado por usar nossa plataforma!');
}
```

`->name` being the field from your users table which contains the users name.

Comment: thanks, I did it another way, but this one of you looks more like it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way and it worked.

```
// Class Notify
private $user;
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}


//metho mail() Notify
->greeting('Olá, ' . $this->user->name)



 //Controller
  $user->notify(new CreateNewCompany($user));
```